# Why is ImageMagick not converting EPS to PNG correctly (Not retaining color)

Tags: colors, png, imagemagick, converters, eps

I am trying to use ImageMagick to convert an EPS to a PNG and hav ing difficulties.
The image does convert to a PNG, but with defects (see below).

[Converted PNG](http://smashforceteamgo.com/images/thumb_20-%5Bbrush%5D.png)

I have tried a number of different converts and options and none seem to make a difference.
Is anyone aware of what the issue may be and a way to resolve it.

Some examples of what I have tried so far are:

```
convert 20-[brush].eps -colorspace RGB thumb_20-[brush].png

convert 20-[brush].eps -colorspace sRGB thumb_20-[brush].png

convert 20-[brush].eps -colorspace CMYK thumb_20-[brush].png 

convert 20-[brush].eps -depth 4 -strip thumb_20-[brush].png

convert 20-[brush].eps -channel RGB -seperate thumb_20-[brush].png 
convert thumb_20-[brush]-1.png thumb_20-[brush]-2.png thumb_20-[brush]-3.png -channel RGB \ -combine combined.png
```

There has also been many other attempts but I've began to loose track of what I've tried

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have noted it appears to be an issue with the original EPS file as I have now tested with outsourced and conversion works - the question may now be better as - "Why did my EPS created in photoshop not convert?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noted it appears to be an issue with the original EPS file as I have now tested with outsourced and conversion works - the question may now be better as - "Why did my EPS created in photoshop not convert?"